# Normalized area of the dark region is $4\pi$.

Tags: contest-math, surfaces

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}$ $\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$ $\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$ $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$

> **IMO 1982, Longlisted Problem 10.**
> Let $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ be the radii of $n$ pairwise disjoint spheres.
> Let $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ be the areas of the set of points of each sphere from which one cannot see any point of any other sphere.
> Prove that
> $$
> \frac{A_1}{r_1^2} + \cdots + \frac{A_n}{r_n^2} = 4\pi
> $$

I could solve the problem assuming $r_1= \cdots = r_n = 1$. Here is the solution for this special case.

Let $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ be the centers of the spheres, and let us denote the sphere with center $p_i$ as $S_i$.
Let $S^2$ denote the unit sphere in $\R^3$.
For $v\in S^2$, we say that the point $p_i+v$ on $S_i$ is **visible** from $S_j$, where $j\neq i$, if $\ab{v, p_i-p_j}> 0$.
The **dark region** $D_i$ of $S_i$ is defined as the part of $S_i$ not visible from any other sphere.
Thus $A_i$ is the area of $D_i$.

Note that if $v\in S^2$ and $p_i+v$ is not visible from $S_j$, for some $j\neq i$, then $p_j+v$ is visible from $S_i$ (except for a measure zero set of points $v$ in $S^2$).
Thus for any $v\in S^2$, we have at most one $i\in \set{1, \ldots, n}$ such that $p_i+v$ is in the dark region of $S_i$ (again, modulo a set of measure zero in $S^2$).
Define
$$
D_i' = \set{v\in S^2:\ p_i+v\in D_i}
$$
From the above discussion it is clear that $D_1', \ldots, D_n'$ are pairwise (measure theoretically) disjoint.

We show that their union is all of $S^2$, up to a set of measure $0$.
Let $v$ in $S^2$ be arbitrary and assume that for each $i\in \set{1, \ldots, n}$ there is $\vp(i)\in \set{1, \ldots, n}\setminus{\set{i}}$ such that $p_i+v$ is visible from $S_{\vp(i)}$.
Thus $\ab{v, p_i-p_{\vp(i)}} > 0$.
Since there are finitely many spheres, there must be $i\in \set{1, \ldots, n}$ and a positive integer $k\geq 2$ such that $\vp^k(i) = i$.
Thus we have
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{k-1} \ab{v, p_{\vp^r(i)} - p_{\vp^{r+1}(i)}} > 0
$$
which is a contradiction since the left hand side of the above is zero.

So we have that the area of $D_i'$ is same as the area of $D_i$ and the $D_1', \ldots, D_n'$ partition $S^2$ (module a set of measure zero).
Thus we have the desired result.

Comment: Cool. My first reaction would be to take the convex hull of the spheres, and apply Gauss-Bonnet to its surface. Not sure it works (and not in the scope of IMO), but worth a try IMO.

Comment: I'd like to see an advanced solution too if one exists. And your comment makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I just think, by visual inspection more than anything else, that the Gaussian curvature of that surface vanishes outside of the dark areas. Somebody who is more experienced in differential geometry than I am can hopefully say more.

Comment: I am convinced you have a proof. Thanks. That's great. But I'll wait for an elementary approach.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is so smart, amazing proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote by $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n$ the $n$ disjoint spheres of radius $r_1, \ldots, r_n$, centered at $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ respectively, and let $D_i$ be the dark region of each one. It's clear that $D_i$ is an open and connected subset of $S_i$ since it's defined by
$$
D_i= \{x\in S_i: \langle x-p_i, p_j-p_i\rangle< -r_i(r_j-r_i), \text{ for all } j\neq i\}.
$$
Following your proof, define the projection maps
$$
\pi_i: D_i\to S^2, \\
x\mapsto \frac{x-p_i}{r_i}.
$$
It's clear that $\pi_i$ is injective. Following your proof, we want to show that
$$
S^2= A\cup\bigcup_{i=1}^n \pi_i(D_i),
$$
where $A$ is a set of measure zero, and
$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^n \pi_i(D_i)\setminus A= \emptyset. 
$$
This would show the claim since then
$$
4\pi= |S^2|= \int_{S^2}\text{d}S= \sum_i\int_{\pi_i(D_i)}\text{d}S= \sum_i\int_{D_i}\frac{\text{d}S}{r_i^2}= \frac{A_1}{r_1^2}+ \ldots+ \frac{A_n}{r_n^2},$$
using the change of variables formula.

For the first claim, observe $v\in\pi_i(D_i)$ if and only if
$$
\langle p_i+r_i v- p_i, p_j-p_i\rangle< -r_i(r_j-r_i),
$$
for all $j\neq i$, equivalently
$$
\langle v, p_j-p_i\rangle< -(r_j-r_i),
$$
for all $j\neq i$. Now, define
$$
A= \bigcup_{i,j=1}^n\{v\in S^2: \langle v, p_i-p_j\rangle=-(r_j-r_i)\}.
$$
This is clearly a set of measure zero. Fix $v\in S^2$. Without loss, we'll show that if $v\notin \pi_2(D_2)\cup\ldots\cup\pi_{n}(D_n)\cup A$, then $v\in \pi_1(D_1)$. But, if $v\notin \pi_2(D_2)\cup\ldots\cup \pi_n(D_n)\cup A$, and $i\in\{2, \ldots, n\}$, there is some $\phi(i)\neq i$ such that
$$
\langle v, p_{\phi(i)}-p_i\rangle>-(r_{\phi(i)}-r_i).
$$
Note that, for $k>l$
$$
\langle v, p_{\phi^k(i)}- p_{\phi^l(i)}\rangle= \sum_{s=l}^{k-1}\langle v, p_{\phi^{s+1}(i)}-p_{\phi^s(i)}\rangle> \sum_{s=l}^{k-1}-(r_{\phi^{s+1}(i)}-r_{\phi^s(i)})= -(r_{\phi^k(i)}-r_{\phi^l(i)}).
$$

Since $\phi:\{2, \ldots, n\}\to \{1, \ldots, n\}$, and $\phi(i)\neq i$, there must me some $k$ such that $\phi^k(i)=1$, otherwise there would be some $k>l$ such that $\phi^k(i)=\phi^l(i)$, but then
$$
0= \langle v, p_{\phi^k(i)}-p_{\phi^l(i)} \rangle> -(r_{\phi^k(i)}-r_{\phi^l(i)})=0,
$$
contradiction. As a result, $\langle v, p_1-p_i\rangle> -(r_1-r_i)$, for all $i\geq 2$ which proves the claim.

For the second claim, let $v\in \pi_i(D_i)\setminus A$, that is
$$
\langle v, p_j-p_i\rangle< -(r_j-r_i),
$$
for all $j\neq i$. Then, $\langle v, p_i-p_j\rangle> -(r_i-r_j)$, i.e., $v\neq \pi_j(D_j)$ for all $j\neq i$.

---

Let me describe why this is the right definition for $D_i$. Let us work on the plane. Suppose $S_1= \partial D(0,r)$, and $S_2= \partial D((-a,0), R)$, for some $a>0$ such that $a> |R-r|$. We want to find the largest $x\in (-r,r)$, such that $(x,\sqrt{r^2-x^2})$ is visible from $S_2$. This means that the tangent
$$
(x, \sqrt{r^2-x^2})+ t(-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}, x),
$$
intersects $S_2$ at a single point. Equivalently, the equation
$$
|(x- t\sqrt{r^2-x^2}, \sqrt{r^2-x^2} +tx)- (-a,0)|=R,
$$
has a unique solution. We may rewrite this equation as:
$$
r^2 t^2- 2a\sqrt{r^2-x^2}t+ (a^2+2xa+r^2-R^2)=0.
$$
This has a unique solution if and only if the discriminant
$$
\Delta= 4a^2(r^2-x^2)-4r^2(a^2+2xa+r^2-R^2)=0,
$$
i.e.,
$$
(ax+r^2)^2= r^2R^2. 
$$
If $r<R$, we want $x>0$ so we take $ax+r^2= rR$. This means that for any $x>\frac{rR-r^2}{a}$, $(x, \pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2})$ is in the dark region of $S_1$, or equivalently when $-ax+0y< -r(R-r)$.

If $r>R$ then we want $x<0$ so we still take $ax+r^2= rR$, resulting in the same equation.

---

I would also like to expand on @JyrkiLahtonen comment since I thought his suggestion was excellent. Another way to do this is note that the convex hull
$$
C= \text{conv}\{S_1, \ldots, S_n\}= D_1\cup\ldots\cup D_n\cup \{\text{cylinders}\}\simeq S^2,
$$
and hence all the curvature of $C$ is concentrated on $D_1, \ldots, D_n$. Now my Gauss-Bonnet
$$
4\pi= \int_{C}K\text{ d} S= \int_{D_1}\frac{1}{r_1^2}\text{ d}S+ \ldots+ \int_{D_n}\frac{1}{r_n^2}\text{ d}S= \frac{A_1}{r_1^2}+ \ldots+ \frac{A_n}{r_n^2}. 
$$

---

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am unable to agree with the definition of the dark region as given in your answer. Suppose there were only two spheres (of different radii). Then according to your definition, the dark region of any of the spheres would be a hemisphere. However, that is not the case. It is possible that I may be missing something simple.

Comment: @caffeinemachine you are right, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I did not realize that the dark region can be determined by a simple inner product condition even when the radii are different. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would approach it.

1. Show that each area $A_i$ is the intersection of several solid caps (obtained through intersections with the other spheres $S_j, j\neq i$). This avoids measure-theoretic concerns.
2. Associate the area to the corresponding solid angle measure. Note that the value of the solid angle measure is $ \frac{A_n}{ r_n^2}$.
3. Show that this association is a bijection with the angle measure of a unit sphere, except possibly at the boundaries of $A_i$.

- Given any point on the unit sphere, rotate the sphere+confiuration so that the point is at the bottom. Then, we map this point to all the lowest point in the configuration.
- It is possible that  there are multiple lowest points in the configuration.  Show that this occurs only on the boundary of $A_i$.

4. Hence, the sum of $ \frac{ A_n}{ r_n^2}$ is the solid angle measure of the unit sphere which is $ 4 \pi$.

Note: There are similarities to IMO 2002/6 which involves unit circles. A particular solution uses the fact that the convex hull of the circles has curved perimeter of $2\pi$, which is similar to the above via the associated central angle measure.
Speaking as a contestant of the IMO 2002, I believe that (but am not fully confident)

- Contestants with a complete proof apart from merely stating this fact without proof were not docked points.
- Merely stating this fact wasn't sufficient to yield partial credit. Those that also tied it to the corresponding angle measure and related it to the question, were given partial credit.